# How to enable horizontal scroll on `less` with trackpad?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, trackpad

I want to use my trackpad in macOS to scroll `less` horizontally. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to scroll within less or within the Terminal window less runs in?

Comment: For me, by default, `less` wraps text to the width of the window, so there's nowhere to scroll horizontally to, because there's nothing 'hiding' to the sides. Can you explain more about what you see, and what you want? Also, which OS version and Mac model you have.

Comment: @benwiggy You can use `less --chop-long-lines` to disable soft-wrapping. I have macOS 13.1.